# Best way to resize multiple pictures?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image-resizing

I have a lot of pictures and I need them all to have the same size because I want to use them on a website in my bootstrap thumbnails.

To resize them all using Gwenview or a program like takes quite a lot of time. So now I was wondering if someone knows a faster way to resize a big amount of pictures?

I can't just define the width and the height in the html, because they would be deformed too extremely. The images are sometimes square, sometimes rectangular. Their sizes vary a lot. (2388*417px / 709*494px / etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to install Kipi: https://extragear.kde.org/apps/kipi/

Once Kipi is installed you should have batch processing options under the Plugins-menu (in Gwenview that is).

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I installed them with `sudo apt-get install kipi-plugins` Can you tell me how exactly i can use them? I opened Gwenview but it doesn't show me anything when I click on "Plugins". I already rebooted my computer to check if this was the problem but it didn't fix it.

Comment: I just read that kipi-plugins are using kde 4. I have kde 5. Do you know if there's a workaround for that?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that could be a big problem. I used them under KDE4 (I'm mainly on Windows these days). And else this will probably work: http://forum.linuxcareer.com/threads/1644-Batch-image-resize-using-linux-command-line ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Imagemagick was a good solution for that. In my case I had to use another command called `mogrify` but this one worked perfect!